# SQL query to pivot columns

Tags: sql

I have a table 'tbl_marks' like this,

```
st_index    Subject     Term     Marks
----------------------------------------
13110       Maths       1        60
13110       Maths       2        70
13110       Maths       3        80
13110       Science     1        70
13110       Science     2        70
13110       Science     3        80
13111       Maths       1        90
13111       Maths       2        70
13111       Maths       3        80
13111       Science     1        80
13111       Science     2        70
13111       Science     3        80
```

then I need to show following result after filter the term by 1

```
st_index    Maths     Science    
--------------------------------
13110       60         70        
13111       90         80
```

for the movement I am with this code, not having expected output

```
SELECT st_index,
    (case when subject='Maths' then marks end )as 'Maths',
    (case when subject='Science' then marks end )as 'Science'
FROM tbl_marks
where term=1 
group by st_index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, all you need is to wrap your `CASE EXPRESSION` with an aggregation function, like `MAX()/MIN()` :

```
SELECT st_index,
       MAX(case when subject='Maths' then marks end) as Maths,
       MAX(case when subject='Science' then marks end) as Science
FROM tbl_marks 
where term=1
group by st_index
```

By the way - this is called conditional aggregation, does the same functionality as pivot, but they are two different things.